# Firefox File Upload window not appearing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, file-upload

In my Rails app, I have a file_field input in my form to allow the user to upload a file.  When the user uploads the file, I use ajax to submit the form automatically.  It works fine in Safari and Chrome, but in Firefox, the File Upload window (where the user selects which file they want to upload) never appears when I click on my "upload video" button, and the form is automatically submitted without any file.

Is there something special to get File Uploads to work in Firefox?

Here is my code:

```
    <div id="uploadVideoWrapper" title="Add Video">
      <button class="btn btn-primary uploadVideoButton">
        Upload Video
      </button>
      <input class="video_file_upload_field" id="video_video_path" name="video[video_path]" onchange="return validateFileExtension(this)" type="file">
    </div>
```

And my Ajax to submit the form once the user uploads a file (video.js.coffee.erb):

```
jQuery ->
  $('#videoEmbedModal').fileupload
    dataType: "script"
    add: (e, data) ->
        console.log('uploaded video')
        types = /(\.|\/)(mov|mp4|avi)$/i
        file = data.files[0]
        size = file.size/(10e5)
        size_limit = 25 # file size limit is 50 mb
        if (types.test(file.type) || types.test(file.name)) && (size < size_limit)
            $('#video_submit').html('Saving...')
            $('#videoFileName').html(file.name)
            $('.uploadVideoButton').attr('disabled', true)
            $('.video_file_upload_field').attr('disabled', true)
            $('.loadingIcon').show()
            $('#images').append('<div class="placeholder video" style="background-image: none">uploading video...<br><%=image_tag("icons/loading.gif")%></div>');
            $('.placeholder').hide();
            data.context = $(tmpl("video-upload", file))
            # $('#videoUploadProgress').append(data.context)
            data.submit()
        else if (size > size_limit)
            alert("Your video is larger than 50 MB and cannot be uploaded.  Please upload to Youtube or Vimeo and embed your video instead.")
        else
            alert("#{file.name} is not a supported video format")
    progress: (e, data) ->
        if data.context
            progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10)            
            # data.context.find('.bar').css('width', progress + '%')
            if progress == 100
                setTimeout ( -> 
                    $('.embedModal').modal('hide');
                    ), 2000
                $('.placeholder').show();
                document.getElementById("images").scrollTop = document.getElementById("images").scrollHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the input was offset from my button so the user wasn't actually clicking on the input field when the button was clicked.  A simple solution, but it took some time to figure out!